# How can i specify snmp community string in prometheus with snmp_exporter as the exporter?

Tags: prometheus, snmp

I am not sure whether i should do it in the prometheus.yml file or snmp.yml file. It works with devices that have 'public' as the community string. For example I tried it with a cisco switch. But when i tried it with a palo alto firewall with a different string, prometheus shows the palo alto target as 'down'. I cannot seem to fetch the snmp data using snmp_exporter either.

This is my prometheus.yml file:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: 'snmp_exporter'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['10.10.10.254', '10.10.10.244']
    metrics_path: /snmp
    params:
      module: [if_mib]
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: localhost:9116
```

Any insights?